# Applying CSS properties based on subscribed variable. Dark mode vs light

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to change the CSS property based on if a user has clicked on dark mode or light. I can get the a subscription going to capture the value every time the modes are switch but i want to be able to change certain property's in CSS when the different modes are clicked.

I'm using Angular 9

Any idea on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **BehaviourSubject** RXJS to implement this feature. By default you can set to false and use light mode when ever User clicks the switch using next() method change the behaviour subject to true then dark etc. you have to subscribe to **BehaviourSubject** variable on init and handle the response.

You can have the reference at [BehaviourSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject).

I personally implemented this dark mode feature in my project here is the link [telivic.com](https://telivic.com/home) the approach I have used in that site is as followed.Hope this works for you.

```
addDark(){
    document.getElementById('nav').classList.add('dark');
    document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = "#35363A";
     document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].classList.add('dark');
     document.getElementById('modal').style.backgroundColor ="bisque";
     if(this.service.flag){
      document.getElementById('opt').classList.add('dark');
     }
     document.getElementById('gen').style.color="white";
     
  }
  removeDark(){
    document.getElementById('nav').classList.remove('dark');
    document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
     document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].classList.remove('dark');
     document.getElementById('modal').style.backgroundColor ="white";
     if(this.service.flag){
      document.getElementById('opt').classList.remove('dark');
     }
     document.getElementById('gen').style.color="black";
  }
  /*Binded my switch to this function I have used service so that user   dark/light mode preference can be processed in other pages also.*/
  darkMode(){
    this.dark = !this.dark;
    this.userService.setMode();
    if(this.dark){
      this.addDark();
    }else{
     this.removeDark();
      
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: Yes im successfully getting my values from my subscription but my CSS property's are not changing as my values update.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable in ts file,

```js
modeType: string;
```

This will change as 'dark' or 'light' depending on user's selection.

In your html to change the css property use ngClass.
Or use

```html
<div class="{{modeType == 'dark' ? 'dark-property': 'light-property'}}">
```

In your css file,

```css
.dark-property{
 add your "dark" css styles
}

.light-property{
 add your "light" css styles
}
```

Comment: yes this works, but it only changes to the initial class. As the user changes the mode the variable is not binded. eg. initial startup of app goes to light-property, but when user changes to dark mode, the css property does not change to dark-property. I can confirm that my subscription changes the value for the variable, but does not change the CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can use styled-components. One example would be:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const ComponentName = styled.div`
    color: ${props => props.mode === `dark` ? `white` : `black`};
`
```

And then in your render, do this:

```
<ComponentName mode={mode} />
```